# If I know the lambdas for each manifest variable, how would I calculate the correlation matrix in factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

I had a question as it relates to factor analysis. If I know the lambdas for each manifest variable. For example:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
X_{1}=0.7 \xi_{1}+0.1 \xi_{2}+\varepsilon_{1} \\
X_{2}=0.9 \xi_{1}+0.5 \xi_{2}+\varepsilon_{2} \\
X_{3}=0.3 \xi_{1}+0.2 \xi_{2}+\varepsilon_{3}
\end{array}\right\}$

How would I derive the correlation matrix? If you would like to solve it in order to help with the explanation that would be great, but I'm more just asking for a bit of an explanation on how you would calculate when you are given the factor loadings/lambdas as it pertains to factor analysis.

As per the comments the above is of the form:
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
X_{1}=\lambda_{11} \xi_{1}+\lambda_{12} \xi_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{1 m} \xi_{m}+\varepsilon_{1} \\
X_{2}=\lambda_{21} \xi_{1}+\lambda_{22} \xi_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{2 m} \xi_{m}+\varepsilon_{2} \\
X_{3}=\lambda_{31} \xi_{1}+\lambda_{32} \xi_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{3 m} \xi_{m}+\varepsilon_{3}
\end{array}\right\}$

This is why I state that I know the lambdas. My apologies if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Because no lambda symbols $\lambda$ appear here, I have to ask what you might mean by a "lambda for [a] manifest variable"?

Comment: I should of been more explicit, you are right. My bad. The above is of the form: $\left\{\begin{array}{l}
X_{1}=\lambda_{11} \xi_{1}+\lambda_{12} \xi_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{1 m} \xi_{m}+\varepsilon_{1} \\
X_{2}=\lambda_{21} \xi_{1}+\lambda_{22} \xi_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{2 m} \xi_{m}+\varepsilon_{2} \\
X_{3}=\lambda_{31} \xi_{1}+\lambda_{32} \xi_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{3 m} \xi_{m}+\varepsilon_{3}
\end{array}\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you want is:

$\Sigma = \Lambda\Phi\Lambda' + \varepsilon$

Where:

$\Sigma$ is the implied covariance matrix.

$\Lambda$ is the loading matrix (and $\Lambda'$ is the transposed loading matrix).

$\varepsilon$ is the error matrix

$\Phi$ is the factor covariance matrix. If your solution is orthogonal and standardized, then $\Phi$ is an identity matrix, and you can ignore it.

Comment: Just to clarify, would you not add the matrix var($\epsilon$) to the above equation which would be the matrix with variance of unique factor
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\operatorname{var}\left(\varepsilon_{1}\right) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \operatorname{var}\left(\varepsilon_{2}\right) & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \operatorname{var}\left(\varepsilon_{p}\right)
\end{array}\right]$

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, to get the variances right in sigma you need that. I'll add. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I pressed enter too quickly. Is you would add that matrix to the equation above, right?